New camera detection with EDSKD
There's an event for camera being disconnected, but is there a way to detect that a new camera was connected to the system?
Or repeatedly asking for camera list is my best bet?
python or c# or c++
e = EDSDK.EdsGetCameraList(byref(self.CameraList))

This code reloads all cameras.
help me please
